# Extrude as individuals?

Tags: modeling, extrude

I will keep this as simple as possible, I have a cylinder, and i checker select the faces. I extrude, But i want to extrude each face outwards in the direction they are facing, The only way i can extrude all of them at the same time is by scaling upwards and scaling the x-axis.

[image]

Is there someway to extrude each face in the same way if i had only selected one face?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the faces and use "extrude individual"

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Also how would i scale as an individual?

Comment: [S Shift-Z to not scale on the Z-axis](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27368/935) note that scaling will increase the width of the faces as they move outwards.